# django custom admin login page

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a custom auth mechanism for users and I want to use the same for django admin.
All works fine for authenticated users but if an unauthenticated user opens the url /admin he is redirected to /admin/login with the std. login page for admin. I want to redirect to auth/sign-in or block the page.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('admin/login', SignInView.as_view(), name='admin/login'),
    ...
```

Redefining the url like in the code block does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Did you define `LOGIN_URL` in settings.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urlpatterns are searched in order, using the first match, rather than overwitten by later patterns, so you might have better luck with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/login', SignInView.as_view(), name='admin/login'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
```

[Docu for the URL dispatcher for reference:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/%5D)

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.